# НЛО - "нерозпізнаний", "невизначений", "непізнаний" чи "невпізнаний" літаючий об'єкт?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Сьогодні натрапив на обговорення розшифрування абревіатури "НЛО" на Вікіпедії. Користувачі пропонували 4 варіанти: "нерозпізнаний", "невизначений", "непізнаний", "невпізнаний". На жаль, до згоди користувачі дійти не змогли. Проте, зараз є стаття: "[Непізнаний літаючий об'єкт](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82)", але пояснення:

> НЛО — невизначений (невпізнаний) літаючий об'єкт

Отож, всі 4 слова можна знайти в СУМі:

> [НЕВИ́ЗНАЧЕНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/NEVYZNAChENYJ) - точно не встановлений; не зовсім виразний, ясний.
>
> [НЕВПІ́ЗНАНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nevpiznanyj) - якого не можна пізнати.
>
> [НЕРОЗПІ́ЗНАНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nerozpiznanyj) - якого важко відрізнити, розпізнати; **те саме, що
>   непізнаний**.
>
> [НЕПІ́ЗНАНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nepiznanyj) - якого ще не пізнали, не вивчили.

Мені здається, що найкращим варіантом є "нерозпізнаний". Однак, я не впевнений.

Answer (score 1):

Згодна з Вами,  що найкращим варіантом є ***"нерозпізнаний"***. Підтвердження цього варіанту знайшла в цих словниках

[УСЕ (Універсальний словник-енциклопедія)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53405/16724.html)

> НЛО 
>   **нерозпізнаний літаючий об'єкт** (англ. UFO, Undefined Flying Object), предмети чи явища (помічені, зазвичай, випадковими особами),
>   які не вдалося зідентифікувати з жодними відомими об'єктами та
>   явищами; приписувані позаземним цивілізаціям.

[Орфографічний словник української мови:](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53405/130291.html)

> НЛО 
>   *абревіатура* 
>   **нерозпізнаний літаючий об'єкт**  незмінювана словникова одиниця